# Does infinitely differentiable imply analytic?

Tags: derivatives, analyticity

I know that analytic implies infinitely differentiable, but is the converse always true as well?

Comment: Nope. Look up smooth bump functions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes This question should be closed because OP never bothered even to check Wikipedia

Comment: The answer depends on whether you're working over $\Bbb R$ (in which case no) or $\Bbb C$ (in which case yes).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: While "checking Wikipedia" is a natural step for you, knowing a certain body of useful search terms to put material in a useful context, this may not be true of all Community members, or there may be some who have less confidence in Wikipedia than in Math.SE on a given subject.  A better response would be to check for possible duplicates here.

Answer (score 3):

Our old friend $$f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$ is infinitely differentiable and in particular at $x=0$ all its derivatives are zero.  But it is not analytic at $x=0$.

Comment: Isn't this function undefined at 0?  Doesn't this make it not continuous and therefore not differentiable at 0?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, to turn it into a function on the whole real line (actually, the whole complex plain) one must add to its definition $f(0)=0$.  Then it is infinitely differentiable everywhere, but not analytic at $0$.